# How to display timestamps on activity feed

Tags: mobile, ios, activity-feed

I'm designing a mobile iOS app with a predominant focus on an activity feed of salespeople and customers. I'd like to place time stamps on each activity feed item, but am stuck deciding which format of timestamp is most easily read and understood.

**My current implementation:**
[image: the app UI I am working on]

**Twitter for iOS** - very simple:
[image: Twitter for iOS timestamp example]

**Facebook for iOS** - wordy, literal
[image: Facebook for iOS timestamp example]

Answer (score 2):

The standard abbreviation for minutes is **min**, it's familiar and not wordy. **3 min** looks nice ). For easily read you should make it more noticable. Your tools are placement (+ alignment), font and color.

Bottom right placement is not so good, the number looks rather weird and floating.

Comment: +1 for bringing up the problem with its current placement, totally agree